# Regular Expression

Tags: regex, dart

Get The Last Characters  end with (`/`) in include.

The input string is: `xxx/xx/xxx/YERpq9CifKTIC1g`

The result that I want: `/YERpq9CifKTIC1g`

Comment: Edit   : Get The Last Characters end with (/) in include  (/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
/\/[^\/]+$/
```

The theory being to match a `/` followed by any character that isn’t a `/` (`[^\/]`) until the end of the line (`$`).